# HttpTransportSE dá erro "java.io.EOFException" usando KSoap2 no Android

Tags: android, web-service

Estou utilizando a lib KSoap2 no projeto Android, para comunicação com webservice.

Toda a comunicação está dentro de um AsyncTask().

Em alguns momentos de acesso ao método, ocorre uma exception:

*"java.io.EOFException"*

Fiz uma pesquisa pela Internet e foi recomendado a incluir a propridade "Connection/close":

[fonte] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ksoap2-android/nwx0MCo4js4/FYJSxWeiEkQJ

Porém mesmo adicionando, as vezes o erro volta a aparecer:

```
HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(WSBase.URL);
try {

        transport.getServiceConnection().setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

        transport.debug = true;
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION + methodName, envelope);

        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        return new WsRetorno(Integer.parseInt(response.getPropertyAsString("retXml").toString()), 
                response.getPropertyAsString("desRet").toString());

} catch (Exception e) {
    return new WsRetorno(-1, e.getMessage());
}
```

Alguém que tenha passado por isso saiba o porque e como resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentente resolveu meu problema adicionando dois comandos adicionais ao código:

```
transport.getServiceConnection().setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

Desde então não apresentou mais erros.